# A problem on verify conditional expectation

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, conditional-probability

> Suppose X and Y are independent.Let $\varphi $ be a function with $E(|\varphi(X,Y)|)< \infty$ and let $g(x)=E(\varphi(x,Y))$.The conclusion is $E(\varphi(X,Y)|X)=g(X)$

So the first step is to show $g(X)\in \sigma(X)$ and I don't know how to do.

There is a theorem "If $g$ is a continuous function ,then $g(X)\in \sigma(X)$".It seems no other theorems about measurable.But I think $g$ need not to be continuous.

Comment: Hint: if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $E(X|Y)=E(X)$. Try to apply this to $\varphi$. Also note that the problem statement is not correctly written: one must assume $\varphi$ is measurable for the problem to even make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g$ need not be continuous, but it has to be a Borel-measurable function $g: (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. In order to conclude that $g(X)$ is $\sigma(X)/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable, note that $$(\Omega,\sigma(X)) \ni \omega \mapsto X(\omega) \in (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$$ is measurable and that the composition of two measurable functions is measurable (with respect to the corresponding $\sigma$-algebras).

Comment: Good answer. It should be mentioned that we must be careful about the word "measurable" in regards to functions. If $B \equiv \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $M \equiv \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, then we traditionally say that a function is measurable if it is measurable as a function from $(\mathbb{R},L)$ to $(\mathbb{R},B)$. Yet compositions of such functions are *not* always measurable, because if $A$ is a Borel set and $f,g$ are measurable, then $(f \circ g)^{-1}(A) = g^{-1}(f^{-1}(A))$ is an inverse image of a set in $L$, not $B$.

Comment: In probability theory one usually dodges this problem by considering only Borel measurable functions, although this has its own pitfalls.

Comment: @Ian I have replaced "measurable" by "Borel-measurable". From my point of view compositions of measurable functions are measurable, because I always assume (without mentioning this explicitly) that they are measurable with respect to suitable $\sigma$-algebras (i.e. $f:(X,\mathcal{A}) \to (Y,\mathcal{B})$ msb. and $g: (Z,\mathcal{C}) \to (X,\mathcal{A})$ msb. $\Rightarrow f \circ g: (Z,\mathcal{C}) \to (Y,\mathcal{B})$-msb.)

Comment: Indeed, in the abstract context, this is the better way of thinking about it. Unfortunately, in the context of integration, one is really forced to deal with functions which are measurable from $L$ to $B$, because going from $B$ to $B$ has issues with subsets of null sets, while going from $L$ to $L$ removes too many functions from consideration.

Comment: the main problem is "why $g$ is measurable" ?

Comment: @paradox In this case, you have to clarify the measurability assumptions on $X,Y,\varphi$. Without any further measurability assumptions, the claim does not hold, see Ian's comment.

Comment: @saz If $X,Y,\varphi$ is measurable,I don't know how to prove $g$ is measurable since it is a expectation,not a compostion of two measuable functions.Or I have to assume $g$ is measurable directly?

Comment: @paradox Yes, the measurability of $g$ follows from Fubini's theorem. If $$(x,\omega) \mapsto \varphi(x,Y(\omega)) \tag{1}$$ is measurable, then by Fubini's theorem $x \mapsto \mathbb{E}\varphi(x,Y)$ is measurable. Note that $(1)$ is satisfied e.g. if both $(x,y)\mapsto \varphi(x,y)$ and $X,Y: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ are measurable.

Comment: @saz I see，thanks a lot.